# Why does my Map change when I update a keySet?

Tags: apex, map

I have an Apex Map and I get the keySet from it. I can iterate over the values, but if I update the keySet (e.g. by deleting entries) the map is also updated (so entries for the deleted keySet entries disappear). Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2):

It's common to see novice developers work with with the assumption that you can manipulate the `keyset` in such a way. For example instead of using `containsKey`, you might see:

```
if (myMap.keyset().contains(someKey)) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

If you want a copy you can act on without affecting the `Map`, use `clone`:

```
Set<KeyType> keys = myMap.keyset().clone();
// now manipulating the Set will not affect the Map
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the keySet it's backed by the map, just like in Java. Any change to the Map updates the keySet and vice versa. That means you can delete entries from the keySet, for example, in order to remove those keys' values from the map. Or you can add entries to the map and the keySet will include the keys for the new entries.

This behaviour isn't currently in the official documentation (which it should be), but I can't see that Salesforce would change this behaviour in future API versions since this is exactly how Java works (and that's what Apex is based on).